# Using Enums In Javascript

Tags: javascript, enums

I have the following ENUM in my Javascript:

```
var letters = { "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3.....}
```

And to use this I know use:

```
letters.A
```

But I was wondering if there was a way that i could replace A with a variable. I have tried something like

```
var input = "B";

letters.input;
```

but this does not work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect `letters.input` to mean something when you never defined `letters.input` in the first place?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin letters is the enum and input is in replace of the hardcoded A in the first line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Bracket Notation Member Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
letters[input];
```

It expects a string, so `letters.B == letters["B"]`, and:

```
var letters = { "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3 },
    input = "B";
console.log(letters[input]);
```

outputs `2`.

Comment: @row1 I cant yet ... time limt